# Strip JSON tags when rendering object data in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am rendering This piece of JSON(1) using angular.js 1.6, The title and description seem to load, however I am unable to get the url from the images property, it currently displays it like this :

```
 <img ng-src="{"original": "https://xxx-export.s3.amazonaws.com/images/products/2016/12/product_1003_2.jpg"}">
```

How would I go about just getting the url to render in my template?

(1)This is the reference for of my json object:

```
   var items = [
      {
          "id": 61,
          "title": "Title 1",
          "description": "Desc",

         "images": [
              {
                  "original": "https://xxx-export.s3.amazonaws.com/images/products/2016/12/product_1003_2.jpg"
              },
              {
                  "original": "https://xxx-export.s3.amazonaws.com/images/products/2016/12/product_1003_5.jpg"
              },
              {
                  "original": "https://xxx-export.s3.amazonaws.com/images/products/2016/12/product_1003_3.jpg"
              }

          ]
];
```

(2) This is the how the data is being displayed in my template

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Item">
   <img ng-src="{$item.images[0]$}" />
    <h4>{$item.title$}</h4>
    <p>  {$item.description$} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe you're looking to do `<img ng-src="{$item.images[0].original$}"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing the object in your `images` collection and not the object's property that contains the url. Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Item">
   <img ng-src="{$item.images[0].original$}" />
    <h4>{$item.title$}</h4>
    <p>{$item.description$}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got to dereference one more time! You're getting `items[n].images[0]`, which is giving you something like `{ "original": "... url..." }`.

You just need to get the `original` entry from that object. Replace

```
<img ng-src="{$item.images[0]$}" />
```

With:

```
<img ng-src="{$item.images[0].original$}" />
```